# Remove junction box (no viable screws)

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, installation, recessed-lighting, diy-vs-pro

I'm like 90% through a remodel but I want to add some recessed lighting so I need to remove this junction box. There's the same style junction box in my bathroom that needs to be moved as well. This has me stumped!

[image]

Comment: Is that fed by conduit? Undo all the little rings (locknuts) and pull.

Comment: Looks like EMT... x4; doesn't *need* any screws. But if you want to recess the box you're going to need a tight radius bender... after you pull all the wires out, and take the 4 conduits down... after you gut the ceiling. But there's a reason they used a pancake in the first place and then over filled it....

Answer (score 3):

Often these ceiling boxes will have a piece on top that goes to a joist or between joists, [like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-Round-1-1-2-in-Deep-15-3-cu-in-Metallic-Ceiling-Fan-Light-Fixture-Box-and-Brace-Kit-for-New-Work-CMB150-NB/205383182):

[image: ceiling box]

Comment: Dang, I was hoping that wasn't the case. Welp, time to tear down a bit of the drywall. Thanks! I'll report back on how it goes!

Comment: @DarnellWelcher Not that I'm ever against tearing down the drywall, but all that's going to show you is four conduits coming through bespoke holes in joists that won't push up the inch-plus you're looking for. Prepare to *go big* or don't bother.